# File size increasing after extraction?

Tags: python, html, text-files, filesize

This is a pretty general question, and I don't even know whether this is the correct community for the question, if not just tell me.

I have recently had an html file from which I was extracting ~90 lines of HTML code (total lines were ~8000). I did this with a simple Python script. I stored my output (the shortened html code) into a text file. Now I am curious because the file size has **increased**? what could cause the file to get bigger after I **extracted** some part out of it?

File size before: 319.374 Bytes
File size after: 321.516 Bytes

Is this because of the different file formats html and txt?

Any help or suggestions appreciated!

Code:

```
import glob
import os
import re


def extractor():
    os.chdir(r"F:\Test")  # the directory containing my html
    for file in glob.iglob("*.html"):  # iterates over all files in the directory ending in .html
        with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f, open((file.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + ".txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as out:
            contents = f.read()
            extract = re.compile(r'StartTag.*?EndTag', re.S)
            cut = extract.sub('', contents)
            if re.search(extract, contents) is not None:
                out.write(cut)
            out.close()
extractor()
```

EDIT: I also tried using ".html" instead of ".txt" as filem format for my output file. However the difference still remains.

Comment: Have you done a simple **diff** of the two files?  This should show the difference  quite clearly.  HTML is generally stored as text, but the **.html** extension flags its usage.

Comment: if you say extracted, what do you mean? would you mind to show some of your code if possible?

Comment: Just to be clear - the size of the larger file increased from ~311KB (319,374 bytes) to ~313KB (321,516 bytes) after extracting the 90 lines, correct?

Comment: @Prune: The difference of the two files is negative (Short Output file is bigger than input HTML), so I don't know how to get a reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: @J.Titus: That's right. Basically it is the same file one time with ~8000 lines of HTML code in html format and after extracting with about ~7910 lines but in txt format

Comment: @Cid-EL: I'll add my code

Comment: @FlorianSchramm: I don't mean comparing the sizes; I mean to run the **diff** command (file comparison) on the two files, to see exactly where the differences lie.

Comment: @Prune: No I didn't. Never heard of this command until now. I'll give it a try

Comment: @Prune: This command will not be useful for me as I exactly know and can see which lines I extracted. Using Notepad++ I can clearly see by opening both files at the same time where my RegEx extracted a part of the document. The difference in extracted lines matches exactly the difference of my total lines of both documents....

Comment: If anyone is still interested: I uploaded twp files (one original HTML document and the referring txt document without the extracted part):
https://www.dropbox.com/home/FileSizeDifference
Couldn't figure out the difference yet....

Answer (score 0):

This code does not write to the original HTML file.  Something else must be causing the increased file size .

Comment: You are absolutely right. The Code iterates through my directory, opens each html file, reads each file, deletes the part of the document that matches my RegEx and prints the result to a new created text file.